# How can I force Firefox to revalidate for a specific site?

Tags: firefox, browser-cache

Basically, I would like Firefox to behave as if all responses from example.com carried the "Cache-Control: no-cache" header. I have searched the Mozilla addons site and there is a boatload of hits for "add http headers" but on closer inspection they all modify just the request headers. Perhaps there is another way of doing this, or maybe there isn't :-(

Comment: Duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/985920/how-can-i-force-firefox-to-revalidate-for-a-specific-site

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it for an specific site, but this is the equivalent setting to IE's "Check for newer versions of Stored Pages: Every time I visit the webpage" in Firefox:

Type in the address bar **about:config**, then search for **browser.cache.check_doc_frequency**. Set its value to **1**, which means the website will always load the newest content every time you access it.

Source: http://kb.mozillazine.org/Browser.cache.check_doc_frequency

Comment: Yes, I know about that setting.  But revalidating everything will be quite slow for complex sites.  That's why I want a solution (or rather a workaround) for a specific site.

Comment: I see. If you're developing a website or something like that you could just reload the site with "CTRL + F5". Otherwise I really don't know how.